# Errr 'mongo.js:L112 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L112'

Tags: linux, mongodb, centos, mongoose

I can't connect to [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB). In Ubuntu it works, but I'm working in [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) now. This is the error message:

> MongoDB shell version: 2.4.2
>   connecting to: test
>   Sat Apr 20 07:22:09.390 JavaScript execution failed: Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L112
>   exception: connect failed

I tried removing the `mongod.lock` file, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't started mongod: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/#control-mongodb

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try to remove /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock and restart mongdo service

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo service mongodb restart
```

Comment: does this delete any current databases on mongo?

Answer (score 79):

If you are running Ubuntu, then there is an issue with folder ownership.

Run these commands:

1. Stop the MongoDB service

   ```
   sudo service mongodb stop
   ```
2. Remove the MongoDB lock file

   ```
   sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
   ```
3. Change ownership from root to the MongoDB path

   ```
   sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/
   ```
4. Start the MongoDB service

   ```
   sudo service mongodb start
   ```
5. Test the mongo application

   ```
   mongo
   ```

Then you will be able to execute successfully (I hope).

Reference: [an answer on Stack Exchange site *Database Administrators* to *Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:91 when changing mongodb data directory*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23438/error-couldnt-connect-to-server-127-0-0-127017-src-mongo-shell-mongo-js91-wh/23441#23441)!

Comment: Better than what i usually do to repair mongodb :D

Comment: That worked for me! My VM was shut down forcedly and on boot mongodb was acting silly. This solution worked well.

Comment: This works for CentOS as well, but you should use `mongod` instead of `mongodb` username, `/var/lib/mongo/` dir instead of `/var/lib/mongodb/` and `sudo service *mongod* start` instead of `sudo service *mongodb* start`

Comment: I ran into the same problem. I have done all the above and works fine. However, when I try to connect to mongodb instance from my app I get error `failed to connect to [undefined:27017]`. I am using mongoose 3.8.1 Any idea what am still missing?

Comment: @gabeno I think you are using default connect method.
instead of `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myapp');` , 
use `mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database');`. Please refer [api](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) for more details

Comment: @sumitramteke I sorted the problem. I am relying on runtime config options for the database connection so I had to set `NODE_ENV` on the terminal and it worked fine.

Comment: @gabeno Great! Thanks for the query anyway.

Answer (score 16):

This method only works if you want to repair your data files without preserving the original files. To find where you dbpath resides, use

```
vim /etc/mongodb.conf
```

Check for option `dbpath=`.

(I have `dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb`.)

Default: `/data/db/`

Typical locations include `/srv/mongodb`, `/var/lib/mongodb` or `/opt/mongodb`.

Replace the **/var/lib/mongodb** with your **dbpath**

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ --repair
sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ --journal
```

(Make sure that you leave you terminal running in which you have run the above lines. Don't press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or quit it.) Type the command to start `mongo` now in another window.

I hope this works for you! For those who want to repair your data files while preserving the original files, see [`mongo` recover](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/).

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me on OSX. I installed mongodb using homebrew and the path to the configuration file was /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in the past. In my case, I had insufficient free space for journal files. Freeing some space solved the problem.

Comment: actually it was the same pb for me !

Comment: Check the log files in 
"tail -f /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log"
Then you will get to know the exact issue.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why @lkrzysiak answer was downvoted: it worked for me ! Insufficient free space CAN be the source of this error that I got too, see the logs I got:

```
    Mon Aug 12 17:02:59.159 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
    Mon Aug 12 17:02:59.159 [initandlisten] 
    Mon Aug 12 17:02:59.159 [initandlisten] ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
    Mon Aug 12 17:02:59.159 [initandlisten] Please make at least 3379MB available in /var/lib/mongodb/journal or use --smallfiles
    Mon Aug 12 17:02:59.159 [initandlisten] 
    Mon Aug 12 17:02:59.159 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals, terminating
    Mon Aug 12 17:02:59.159 dbexit: 
    Mon Aug 12 17:02:59.159 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
```

After some cleaning to free some space, it worked like a charm !

Comment: I really don't get why I was downvoted here... I provided an answer that worked for me and documented it... I wish I could downvote your downvote, which is clearly an "egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post" whereas mine is not... Gentle reminder: "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect" [official source](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. Running mongod inside bin (where you have your mongodb installed) worked for me. I also had insufficient space.

Answer (score 0):

You also get this error if you've changed the default port for mongoDB in /etc/mongo.conf

To connect via the shell in this case use:-

```
$mongo 127.0.0.1:your_new_port_number
```

OR

```
$mongo -u <user> -p <pass> --host <host> --port your_new_port_number
```

from [MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo--port)

Answer (score 0):

It could be combination of $PATH and Permission issue.

Try following steps given below:

Update your $PATH variable to point to your MongoDB bin file. In my case brew install MongoDB to this folder:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.6/
```

In order to update your $PATH variable, do following:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/paths
```

Then, press ‘i’ to insert text in Vi and append the your MongoDB path to the end of the ‘paths’ file and restart the terminal.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.6/bin
```

Use ‘Esc : w q’ to save and exit from Vi editor.

Use echo to display your path variable:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.6/bin
```

Now try to check the Mongo version, if you get following, then you are on the right track!

```
$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
```

Now we need to create the database directory. I used the default ‘/data/db’ location suggested in MongoDB docs. I also created a log directory to avoid any permission issues while Mongo tries to create any logs. Change ownership and that will do the job.

```
$ sudo mkdir /data/db
$ sudo mkdir /data/log
$ whoami
username
$ chown -R username /data
```

Now, we will create a default config file for MongoDB to be provided for the first time we run ‘mongod’ command. Now, I will also like to point out that ‘mongod’ will start a service, which will listen for incoming data connections. This is similar having ‘$service mysqld start’ executed.Let’s go ahead and create the config file. Please keep in mind that I have created very basic config file. However, you can add many other variables to configure MongoDB. This is the first time I am playing with MongoDB, so I just know as much as I read on MongoDB docs!I created ‘mongodb.conf’.

```
$ sudo vi /etc/mongodb.conf
```

Add following:

```
fork = true
port = 27017
quiet = true
dbpath = /data/db
logpath = /data/log/mongod.log
logappend = true
journal = true
```

Please note that the default port for MongoDB server is 27017. Use your own path for dbpath and logpath you created in Step – 5. Don’t forget to close and save the conf file.

Now we are all set to start our MongoDB service. Open two instances of Terminal.In Terminal 1, type in:

```
$ sudo mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 3516
all output going to: /data/log/mongod.log
child process started successfully, parent exiting
```

If you get above message, then know that you have successfully started your Mongod service.

Now, to connect to it, in Terminal 2 type following:

```
$mongo test
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings:
Tue Sep 3 16:55:43.527 [initandlisten]
Tue Sep 3 16:55:43.527 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
>
```

Ignore the warnings, but you are successfully connected to the ‘test’ database! Cool!

That's all. I applied this solution, when I tried to install copy of MongoDB on my Mac for the first time. See if this help you too.

For detailed post you can go here - http://arcanebytes.com/2013/09/03/mongodb-installation-on-mac-os-x/#comment-1036112094.

I hope it helps!

Cheers,
Chinmay

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @ZachSaucier thanks for heads up! I have modified the post. :) This was my first reply ever on Stackoverflow! :) Cheers.