# Mongodb failing on Debian

Tags: mongodb, debian

I'm building a MongoDB VM and just cannot get it too work. The output is as follows:

```
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
[master 462b01d] saving uncommitted changes in /etc prior to apt run
 Author: root <root@mongo>
 1 files changed, 5 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)
Setting up mongodb-10gen (2.4.5) ...
Starting database: mongodb failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mongodb, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mongodb-10gen (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
configured to not write apport reports
                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-10gen
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@mongo:~#
```

I've been following the official [install instructions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/) from the mongodb website. I found [this patch fix](https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/attachment/24512/init.d.patch) but this doesn't fix the error either, just throws a new one. I've also seen removing a bad package from dpkg/status can fix the error but I wouldn't even know where to start.

**EDIT 1**

I followed the steps in the top [voted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120397/mongo-jsl112-error-couldnt-connect-to-server-127-0-0-127017-at-src-mongo-she) and now I can access the mongo shell, but when I `service mongodb start` it still says failed. I wasn't able to access the shell before so that's something, yeah?

```
root@mongo:~# service mongodb start
Starting database: mongodb failed!
root@mongo:~# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5
connecting to: test
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
        http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
        http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
> ^C
bye
root@mongo:~#
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't find any traces in the logs:

```
tail -f -n50 /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
```

you should try to start the server in foreground:

```
sudo -u mongodb mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/
```

and see what's happening.
For instance, I had a locale problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your log "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

Paste your log here please.

Could be related to several things. How much hdd space have you got free?
Could be related to journaling. 
MongoDB by default takes a minimum of 3379MB in /journal
Depending on the reason you are installing MongoDB you can either change the configuration to use "smallfiles" which will take up to 512MB files, although it will make it slower as it grows, since the files will be separated, OR disabling journalling which is not advisable.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same error message.  In my case, the issue was that the locale I had specified in the $LOCALE environment (en_US.UTF-8) variable wasn't recognised by Linux.

(I was also getting warnings about setlocale whenever I opened a bash shell.)

In my case doing the following before installing worked:

```
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```